# AWS IMDS runs on a special link local IP 169.254.169.254 - Is the IMDS running on same EC2 machine about which info is queried?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS IMDS (Instance Metadata Service) runs on a special link local IP address of 169.254.169.254 - Is the IMDS running on the same EC2 instance (& if so, is the link local IP address configured on Primary network interface of same EC2 instance?)

Or is the IMDS running on a separate instance with a link local IP address of 169.254.169.254?

When an application in an EC2 instance makes a request to IMDS, how does the packets of the request flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IMDS isn't really running on an EC2 instance at all, it is running on the [hypervisor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-overview-security-processes/hypervisor.html) level. See this illustration:

[image: EC2 Virtual Servers]

The hypervisor is intercepting the request to `169.254.169.254` and returning the information about the EC2 virtual machine it is managing.

Comment: Good to know this info - Thank you.